# C# - Get selected cell's row's first cell's value

Tags: c#, datagridview

My question sounds pretty weird, but my problem is that I don't know how to get a selected cell's row's FIRST cell's value.

For example:

column1  column2  column3
item1    item2    item3

Let's say I select item2, now how could I get item1's value?

Thanks!

Comment: What technology are you using? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? Excel?

Comment: Row of what?  Is this in a spreadsheet?  A database?

Comment: Eh, selected cell/row/value in what context? Excel? DataTable? HTML? More details please!

Comment: We don't know what type you're talking about, which makes it very hard to give any advice.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? ASP.NET MVC? Which control?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using C# .NET, and dataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using a DataGridView?  If so, look at the `DataGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0]`.

Comment: I only select 1 cell not a compete row.

Comment: You can still use the "SelectedRow" property, I believe.  If not, use the selected cell's "CurrentRow" property.

Comment: It's customary, on this site, to "accept" answers if they're helpful and correct...

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript answer.

You've got a C# flag here, but this almost sounds more like raw Javascript on the client. *If* so, navigating the DOM tree gets pretty easy if you use a library such as Prototype. If this is what you're after, check the quick code below. If it's a numerical value you're after, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047820/prototype-get-value-inside-table-cell) post.

```
this_td.up('td');
```

Keep looping "up" the td until you hit the end. Alternatively, you can just instrument the ID of all cells such that it's easy to figure out the first cell's id, and traverse straight to that cell via $("cell_name_12345"). That would be if you want the "name" column, and you're in the "phone" column with an id of "cell_phone_12345", if you know what I mean.